# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 freezes everything but mouse after lid closes and opens

Tags: xfce, freeze, ubuntu-studio, lid

(¿Could anybody please bounty this? I have been having this issue since march)

As title says; I recently installed Ubuntu Studio 19.10 Eoan (Now upgraded to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 Focal Fossa, still having the same exact issue) on my Toshiba Satellite laptop.

I was using Ubuntu 19.10 regularly since it came out, and it worked fine, but when I switched to Studio this happened.

What happens is that after I close and open the lid and then everything but the mouse is unresponsive.

Edit: Changed settings using this terminal `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`(had to install gedit, because Ubuntu Studio doesn't have by default somehow); still the same problem. Formatted the laptop and reinstalled Ubuntu Studio 19.10, still no change. Again changed the settings on `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf` to

```
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

Still no change.

I'm desperate to find a solution.

Also it's a bother to receive only notifications from someone just to tell me that I wrote something wrong instead of giving me any answer to my issue; specially since it's been many days since I've posted this issue.

EDIT 2: XFCE settings are "lock screen" at lid close; but all options give me the same problem.

Googled it, no solution found online gives me an answer or it's meant for regular Ubuntu and are not applicable to Ubuntu Studio.

Edit 3: If I set XFCE to "Presentation mode" I can't even move the mouse after closing or opening the lid; it's not that it won't move, it's that it's gonna be incredibly lagged.

Edit 4: It only happens if I close the lid and in any given time while the lid was closed the laptop runs on battery, or if I close the lid with laptop unplugged. I can still use ctrl+alt+F1, sign in, and use ctrl+alt+F7 and go back to where I was. But otherwise clicking or using the keyboard won't change anything (If a video was paused before closing the lid, the video would start when the lid opens)

Edit 5: Upgraded the system to Ubuntu Studio 20.04, the difference now, is that it happens every time, regardless of the laptop being plugged or not.

This is a really bothersome issue, because I have to go to "ctrl+alt+F1" and reboot the system, because nothing else -that I know of- works; and I have to lose every unsaved work that it's currently open.

Comment: Is it _freezing_ or is there a lot of disk activity.  I've had this on some systems where there is so much disk activity that it looks like it has frozen.  Can you try popping up a terminal and during the _freeze_, can you still type in it?

Comment: No, can't open any terminal, or close any current window, or move, open or close any other thing.
The only thing movable it's the mouse pointer; and that's it.

Comment: Reset the machine and do that before you first close the lid.

Comment: nope, can't write

Comment: Is there any disk activity?  Check the disk light - is it off, on or flashing occasionally

Comment: It doesn't have a disk light, only battery and internet

Comment: Reset the machine, login, from the menu Settings/Settings Editor. There will be a whole bunch of settings.  Have a look at xfce4-power-manager.  Is logind-handle-lid-switch selected?  If it is deselect it.

Comment: The options for XFCE Power Manager doesn't include "logind-handle-lid-switch" as an option.

Comment: Just wondering if it has somehow installed the OS for a desktop instead of a laptop.  I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say, can you please explain?

Comment: I don't know why your installation doesn't have a lid-switch setting if it is a laptop.

Comment: It does have a lid-switch setting, it's just not that one you're saying.
It has two options, one for battery and another for plugged, but none of the settings it's "do nothing"

Comment: I can use "ctrl+alt+F1" IDK if that answers your question.

Comment: in the terminal  and after login,  ,  "sudo systemctl restart lightdm  "  can avoid reboot

Comment: but it will kill your opened programs

Comment: The same issue happens on Xubuntu 20.04. And on Ubuntu 20.04 when the xfce is installed separately. So I guess this is the issue with xfce-ubuntu. I installed Manjaro that also has xfce and different base Linux - arch, no issue like this is spotted, also Ubuntu 20.04 with gnome works ok on the same laptop. So I guess this issue is specific to xfce-ubuntu combination

Answer (score 3):

This seemed to work for me:

1. Remove `xfce4-screensaver`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove xfce4-screensaver
   ```
2. Install `light-locker`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install light-locker
   ```
3. Reboot and test. Xfce power settings are all suspend on lid close.

Comment: thanks. this worked. Xubuntu 20.04, october2021.

Comment: I installed xfce4 on my ubuntu 22.04 system and ran into this problem. `sudo apt remove xfce4-power-manager` in addition to the above seems to have resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

The solution described in [comment #16](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1866686/comments/16) on [Bug #1866686 “20.04 Xubuntu does not resume from suspend” : Bugs : xfce4-power-manager package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1866686) posted by [Arham Amouei](https://launchpad.net/%7Ea-amouei) worked flawlessy for me. Excerpt from that comment:

> I uninstalled xfce4-screensaver for another reason: The system took ~30 secs to suspend. By uninstalling xfce4-screensaver both the problems disappeared.

Comment: Thanks so much for this suggestion - it fixed my weird x freezes on wake! The downside is that uninstalling the screensaver makes the locking mechanisms not work for me. I can't manually lock the screen using the lock button in the menu, and it doesn't lock on sleep. I'm investigating a fix for that now, and I've got a lead in the Arch wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce#Lock_the_screen) (for anyone who may also be investigating this), but any suggestions would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this strange problem and I found a possible workaround, at least it worked for me. I found "where" the problem is, but I don't know "why" it happens, so this is only a workaround, not a true solution.

Open **System Settings** (`xfce4-settings-manager`), click **Power** (this is equal to `xfce4-power-manager-settings` in Terminal), go to **Display** tab. On the right side you'll see an on/off switch (`on` by default). Switch it **off**. (Rebooting is not needed but I would recommend to reboot.)

I've made some tests by switching it on again, and the problem was predictably returning; finally I switched it off, it worked, but after a while a freeze occured once again. So please don't rely on it too much.

By using this method you'll miss power saving functions, but I think it isn't a big price in this case. First, when power saving is important, you can quickly switch your laptop to sleep mode; and second, you can always perform these steps and turn this on again - then just don't forget to keep the lid open.

P.S. A few years ago I've read about a similar problem and I was surprised by the fact that it was linked somehow to GRUB settings. But now I can't remember exactly what was the solution.

Comment: This method brought another inconvenience: resetting of `redshift` settings. I frequently use `redshift` utility to manually adjust screen color temperature (for example, `redshift -PO 4700`), but in Ubuntu Studio 20.04 it is always resetting after lid close/open. In Xubuntu 19.04 `redshift` wasn't resetting and I didn't have any freezes after closing/opening the lid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

1. Edit `logind.conf`:

```
    sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

2. Add the following line: (If it already exists, edit or uncomment):

```
    HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

3. Save/Overwrite.
4. Reboot.